# Xcode not recognizing device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I am having a problem with my Mac where Xcode doesn't recognize my device. Both my phone and mac are up to date with software today. Everytime I plug my phone in it connects and asks if I want my computer to be able to see the images.

Every so often I am alerted with an error:

> Not installed properly , System/Library/Extensions/AppleMobileDevice.kext/

I don't know how to reinstall it or fix this problem. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: This is a solution from 2008 (http://www.cnet.com/uk/news/iphone-or-ipod-touch-not-recognized-restartreinstall-apple-mobile-device-service/). I would check both Xcode and iTunes are up-to-date. Uninstall them and re-install them, if necessary. Apart from this you can try the Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/